# SpringBoot - UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am trying to run my SpringBoot application to check some changes I did in one of the controllers and I am getting the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'inboxApp': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'folderRespository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'folderRepository' defined in io.inbox.folders.FolderRepository defined in @EnableCassandraRepositories declared on InboxApp: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'cassandraTemplate' while setting bean property 'cassandraTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cassandra/CassandraAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession]: Factory method 'cassandraSession' threw exception; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverExecutionException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:660) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]       
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
        at io.inbox.InboxApp.main(InboxApp.java:41) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]   
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
```

To be honest, this was already happening to me since I started to build de app, but after re-running the app the error seemed to disappear and everything went well. However, since I did some minor modifications in my code I cannot run the app anymore... Could you please tell me what do you think is generating this error? As you will see, my classes are super simple and I think everything is being done properly. Thanks for your time.

**InboxApp**

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cass`enter code here`andra.CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableCassandraRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.uuid.Uuids;

import io.inbox.emaiList.EmailListItem;
import io.inbox.emaiList.EmailListItemKey;
import io.inbox.emaiList.EmailListItemRepository;
import io.inbox.email.Email;
import io.inbox.email.EmailRepository;
import io.inbox.folders.Folder;
import io.inbox.folders.FolderRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCassandraRepositories
@RestController
public class InboxApp {

    @Autowired
    FolderRepository folderRespository;

    @Autowired
    EmailListItemRepository emailListItemRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmailRepository emailRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InboxApp.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer sessionBuilderCustomizer(DataStaxAstraProperties astraProperties) {
        Path bundle = astraProperties.getSecureConnectBundle().toPath();
        return builder -> builder.withCloudSecureConnectBundle(bundle);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        folderRespository.save(new Folder("vict0rsan", "Inbox", "blue"));
        folderRespository.save(new Folder("vict0rsan", "Sent", "green"));
        folderRespository.save(new Folder("vict0rsan", "Important", "yellow"));

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            EmailListItemKey key = new EmailListItemKey();
            key.setId("vict0rsan");
            key.setLabel("Inbox");
            key.setTimeUUID(Uuids.timeBased());

            EmailListItem item = new EmailListItem();
            item.setKey(key);
            item.setDestination(List.of("vict0rsan", "abc", "testingUser"));
            item.setSubject("Subject: " + i);
            item.setIsRead(false);
            emailListItemRepository.save(item);

            Email email = new Email();
            email.setId(key.getTimeUUID());
            email.setSender("vict0rsan");
            email.setSubject("Subject:" + i);
            email.setBody("Body: " + i);
            email.setDestination(item.getDestination());
            emailRepository.save(email);
        }
    }
}
```

**FolderRepository**

```
package io.inbox.folders;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FolderRepository extends CassandraRepository<Folder, String>{
    
    List<Folder> findAllById(String id);

}
```

**FolderService**

```
package io.inbox.folders;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FolderService {

    public List<Folder> fetchDefaultFolders(String userId){
        return Arrays.asList(
            new Folder(userId, "Inbox", "white"),
            new Folder(userId, "Sent Items", "green"),
            new Folder(userId, "Important", "red")
        );
    }
    
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>victorsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>inbox-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>inbox-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-jose</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.0</version>
          </dependency>
          
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettytime</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
         </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Edit: I have found out that if I comment all the 'FolderRepository' stuff within the InboxApp, then the same error will be thrown but referring to the next @Autowired repository (in my case 'emailListItemRepository')

Comment: There is a problem when creating the bean 'cassandraSession', but no details are given. Are you sure there is no more stacktrace?

Comment: @Mauricio There is more stacktrace, I have updated the post so you can have the whole info about the error. Thanks

Comment: there is strange entry in the log you posted : "Factory method 'cassandraSessioncassandraSession'"  could be misconfiguration of some kind

Comment: @VladUlshin I thought about it, but I did not find any... I will attach the contenta of my 'application.yml' file where the data conexion with Casaandra is being configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample app code you posted contains this line at the top:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cass`enter code here`andra.CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer;
```

Notice it contains `enter code here` instead of just `cassandra`.

If your code really contains that line, it might be the reason your app can't create a `CqlSession`.

Validate your code and try to compile it again. Cheers!

Comment: You were right @Erick Ramirez, that was causing the issue.